# Run asp.net required field validation only if at least one of the fields in the group is completed

Tags: vb.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a form on an asp.net (VB) page which has 2 sections.

All of section 1 is always required, but section 2 is optional. However, if section 2 is started, then all fields are required.

I'm stuck as to the logic I need to create this validation.

Here's my code:

```
<form runat="server">

    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="field1a" Text="Name" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="field1b" Text="City" />

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="field1aVal" Text="Name Required" ControlToValidate="field1a" InitialValue="Name" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="field1bVal" Text="City Required" ControlToValidate="field1b" InitialValue="City" />
    </div>


    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="field2a" Text="Name" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="field2b" Text="City" />

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="field2aVal" Text="Name Required" ControlToValidate="field2a" InitialValue="Name" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="field2bVal" Text="City Required" ControlToValidate="field2b" InitialValue="City" />
    </div>

    <asp:button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitForm" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Id say use required fields on section 1, but for section two use a custom validator. Something like this.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" 
Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False" 
ErrorMessage="You must select one checkbox or click all offices. " OnServerValidate="OfficeVaildator">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Then in code behind do your logic

Something like this

```
 Sub OfficeVaildator(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
                    If OfficeCheckBoxs.Checked Then
                        args.IsValid = True
                    Else
                        args.IsValid = False
                    End If
 End Sub
```

Obviously that is really simple. You would want to check if the user altered section 2 in anyway, and if he did make him complete all fields to return your server validation arguments true. If he didnt alter section 2 or give it any data right a method that checks that and set your validation to true to allow him to proceed.